# How do I attach a shelf to a plaster wall invisibly?

Tags: wood, furniture

Following this question: [How can I attach two pieces of wood in an invisible way?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/12438/how-can-i-attach-two-pieces-of-wood-in-an-invisible-way/)

I have another - what would be a good way to attach a shelf to a plaster wall, if it is completely supported (i.e. the attachment needs to withstand pulling or shear)?

I don't know if it matters, but the shelf will be next to a wall on two sides.

Answer (score 1):

What about a floating shelf. You wouldn't be able to put much load on it on a partition wall though.

Here's a good [Step by Step on How to Build Floating Shelves](http://www.familyhandyman.com/DIY-Projects/Home-Organization/Bookshelves/how-to-build-floating-shelves/Step-By-Step) from [The Family Handyman](http://www.familyhandyman.com/)

Comment: I don't understand the suggestion